# ComponentKit:CKNetworkImageComponent auto layout to the size of network image

Tags: ios, image, componentkit

CKNetworkImageComponent will not show if I don't set the size param. I guess when the method is called and image not returned, the size is zero.

As I call this method, I don't know the exact size of network image. But when the image returned, I want the component size is exactly the image size.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior isn't supported. You'd have to write your own component to do this.

Comment: Any suggestion about writing such a component?